Stored Proc having UNION operator gives different Column name from Dbeaves and Spring Boot API
I have stored proc which makes use of unions to extract the data. Columns are renamed in first SELECT query as Deal_Id, Deal_Version, Book_Id.
When this proc is executed using Dbeaves Client, columns appear as - Deal_Id,Deal_Version,Book_Id
However when this proc is executed using Spring Boot Rest Endpoint in output columns appear as - Deal_Id,Version,Code
I do not understand why the column names are different in the output
This started happening after I modified the design of stored proc to only use SELECT statements with UNION operators in between.
In older version all the data was stored in a temporary table which had the same column names and at the end was displaying output from that temporary table, the column names in output were same.
SELECT
     @Deal_Id AS Deal_Id,
     a.Version AS Deal_Version,
     foc.Code AS Book_Id
FROM
UNION
---
UNION

